# simultaneous calling of same cuda functions on multiple GPUs using independent streams

Tags: cuda

I am implementing my program on multiple GPUs...
I have two GPUs in my PC and would like to generate two independent streams to handle both devices. I have generated two streams:

```
cudaStream_t *streams; 
streams = (cudaStream_t*) malloc(nstreams * sizeof(cudaStream_t));
for(int j = 0; j < nstreams; j++){
    cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[j]));
}
```

Then I try to call the kernel with the device id as a parameter, per the SDK examples.
According to the device id, cudaDevice is set (cudaSetDevice(dev_ID);) and kernel calls are passed with respective streams:

```
kernel1<<< grid, block,0,streamNo >>>(tex, size);................


for (i = 0;i<gpuN;i++){
    initialize(i);
    printf("initialization done with stream %i on device %i\n", (int)streams[i], i);
    runTest(i);
    printf("running tests done with  %i  stream \n", i);
    deini(i);
    printf("deinitialization is done\n");
}
```

My program is working fine with two different streams, but it runs sequentially.
I would like to run functions simultaneously using both independent streams using both devices. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I am working with CUDA 4.2 using two Tesla 2070.

Answer (score 3):

The streams you create are tied to the context you create them in and it is illegal to use a stream in any context other than the one where it was created. In CUDA 4.x and later, context switching is performed using `cudaSetDevice()`.

So in order to make this you would need to do something like:

```
cudaStream_t *streams[ndevices];

for(int i=0; i<ndevices; i++) {
    cudaSetDevice(i);  
    streams[i] = (cudaStream_t*) malloc(nstreams * sizeof(cudaStream_t)); 
    for(int j = 0; j < nstreams; j++){ 
        cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[j])); 
    }
}
```

which would create `nstreams` streams on each of the devices enumerated `[0,..,ndevices-1]`. Whenever performing an operation on a stream (launching a kernel, executing an asynchronous memcpy, etc), you must execute `cudaSetDevice()` to the correct device context first.

It actually sounds like you might not need to use streams at all. If you have only two streams and two devices, your main kernel launching code could probably be as simple as:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    cudaSetDevice(i);
    kernel1<<< grid, block >>>(tex, size);
}
```

without actually needing to create any streams at all.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.. I am  still having the same issue. When i run my cuda function runTest(i) (it contain many kernels ) by passing i as device_ID on  each device, program is working... but running one device after another... it takes exactly double time as single card. I have not much ideas about streams, i just followed the SDK example to create 2 different streams to handle my two GPU devices... Basically I need my program to run concurrently on both device... looking forward your suggestions..

Comment: What API functions are used inside your `runTest()` routine?

Comment: @vishva are you doung cudaThreadSynchronize() or cuCtxSynchronize() after launching the kernels (or at any point in the algorithm ?). This will serialize your program (i.e. one device after the other).

Comment: sorry..I am still having the same serial execution and take double time... @talonmies, as you suggested i have simply avoided streams and used cudaSetDevice(dev_ID) at the start of each routine!!!! nothing change. Actually I am using cuda_runtime_api with CUDA4.2. runTest(i) is calling  few kernels r more than two years old..there used tex1Dfetch(texC,x)..here texture<short2> texC as global variable....
I am wondering.. i have one global variable set, expecting both device will use simultaneous ..is it right?

Comment: @Pavan, I am not using cudaDeviceSynchronize in between kernel launches.. but few of kernel are already using inside __syncthreads()..do u think this will lead for serializing two devices? Actually I am running a single GPU open source-code and trying to run in 2 Gpus..

Comment: No, __syncthreads() only synchronizes inside thread blocks, so it definitely will not serialize code on separate devices.